# counting number of rows in mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have a table which looks like,

```
 | user_id | url | is_bookmark | is_history    <== schema
```

sample data:

```
[2, "http://www.stackoverflow.com", 1 ,0]
[3, "http://www.stackoverflow.com", 1 ,0]
[4, "http://www.stackoverflow.com", 1 ,1]
[5, "http://www.php.net", 1 ,0]
```

and need the following table,

```
 |  url | total_bookmark | total_history    <== schema
```

sample data for this table

```
["http://www.stackoverflow.com",  3 , 1] 
["http://www.php.net",  1 , 0]
```

I do this using 2 queries, but can it be done in 1?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
 select url , count(*) total_bookmark, sum(is_history) total_history
 from yourtable
 group by url
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56793/1)

Comment: works, but out of curiousity, why did you choose `count(*) total_bookmark` instead of `sum(is_bookmark)`?

Comment: its the same , because you are grouping by url , so it will count all urls :) , you can even use count(1)

Comment: But it won't be the same when `is_bookmark` has a value of 0 or NULL; If that column is implementing a boolean the way we implement them here, we'd get a count of the `TRUE` values using an expression like this: `SUM(is_bookmark<>0)`, though `SUM(is_bookmark)` would also work, because we don't store anything but 0, 1 or NULL in the column.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregate function `sum` on both the columns bookmark and history.

If any of them are unset from book marked or history status, `count` will not work but `sum` works.

Try this:

```
select 
    url,
    sum( is_bookmark ) total_bookmark,
    sum( is_history ) total_history
from table
group by url
```

Comment: NOTE: this assumes that `is_bookmark` and `is_history` are numeric, and will only be assigned values of 0, 1 or NULL (or character which will evaluate to numeric values of 0, 1 or NULL).

Answer (score 1):

Did u mean this ?

```
select count(*) as total,is_bookmark,url,sum(is_history) total_history
from table
group by `url`
```